# Como añadir una funcion a un mapa de imagenes

Tags: javascript, php, html

Buenas a todos, tengo un problema que no doy con la manera de resolverlo, tengo una imagen mapeada pero ahora quiero que cada vez que pinche en la zona mapeada me añada un producto a mi factura, os paso el codigo para que lo veais, a ver si me podeis orientar en donde me estoy equivocando. Graciass!!

```
<table style="width:40%;" align="center">
    <td style="width: 580px;">
    <map name="01"><img src="themes/default/assets/dist/img/02.jpg" usemap="#01">
    <map name="01">
    <area shape="rect" coords="223,112,297,136"  href="#" onclick="add_invoice_item()" data-name="prueba" id="product-0201" value="01">
```

y ahora la funcion para añadir a la factura

```
function add_invoice_item(item) {

if (count == 1) {
    spositems = {};
}
if (item == null) {
    return;
}

var item_id = Settings.item_addition == 1 ? item.item_id : item.id;
if (spositems[item_id]) {
    spositems[item_id].row.qty = parseFloat(spositems[item_id].row.qty) + 1;
} else {
    spositems[item_id] = item;
}

store('spositems', JSON.stringify(spositems));
loadItems();
return true;
}
```

he probado añadirle el elemento (this) pero sigue sin funcionarme, no se porque motivo pero no hace nada. asi lo estoy haciendo ahora

```
<table style="width:40%;" align="center">
<td style="width: 580px;">

<map name="01"><img src="themes/default/assets/dist/img/02.jpg"                                            usemap="#01"> 
<map name="01">
<area shape="rect" coords="223,112,297,136"  href="#" onclick="add_invoice_item(this)" id="product-01" value="01" data-name="prueba">
```

Visto que no estoy consiguiendolo por ahi he visto la posibilidad de añadirle un boton a esas coordenadas pero no tengo ni idea de como meterlo, el codigo de este boton me funciona perfectamente, es decir cuando hago click se añade a la factura. os paso el codigo.

```
<button type="button" data-name="prueba" id="product-0201" value="01" class="btn btn-img btn-flat product"></button>
```

y ya por ultimo por si sirve de refencia, aqui el codigo para que me de el listado de los productos y funciona perfectamente.

```
 <div id="item-list">
  <div class="items">
<?php echo $products; ?>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hola, coclon, bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. Si tienes nueva información que agregar, por favor, [edita tu pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/52382/edit) y añade la información correspondiente, no la pongas como respuesta porque estas son para dar una solución a tu problema. Te invito a [hacer el tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya he aprendido y lo he hecho asi. Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

A simple vista, veo que el método `add_invoice_item` espera un parámetro item que cuando haces la llamada no le pasas. Como tienes esta condición

```
if (item == null) {
    return;
}
```

entiendo que se te está ejecutando todo sin errores pero no hace nada.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder Fernando, he prbado a ponerle dentro la id que tengo en la bases de datos, el nombre pero no hace nada, errores no me presenta solo no me hace nada.  Te muestro la funcion item y a las que llama ella.

Answer (score 0):

En vez de

```
onclick="add_invoice_item()"
```

Tienes que usar

```
onclick="add_invoice_item(this)"
```

Si lo que quieres es pasar el HTMLElement area a la función. Ya que tu área contiene data-attributes, supongo que ya lo tenías pensado así.

Como no tengo idea de lo que son count, spositem ni Settings, te dejo un ejemplo que sólo escribe las propiedades del área cuando ésta es pinchada.

(el área no se ve, pero si mueves el mouse en la cuadrícula verás cómo cambia el cursor)

```js
function add_invoice_item(item) {
  console.log({
    id:item.id,
    name:item.dataset.name,
    value:item.dataset.value
    
  });
  
}
```

```html
<table style="width:400px" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td >
    <map name="01" >
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ch1MhJG.jpg" width="400" height="400" usemap="#01"/>
    <map name="01"/>
    <area  shape="rect" coords="223,112,297,136"  href="#" onclick="add_invoice_item(this)" data-name="prueba" id="product-0201" data-value="01"> </area>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

La siguiente expresión:

```
if (item == null)
```

Siempre será verdadero simplemente **porque no estás pasando un parámetro** a la función `add_invoice_item`. Para solucionar este inconveniente debes pasarle `this` como parámetro el cual **hace referencia** al elemento mismo.

```
<area ...onclick="add_invoice_item(this)"></area>
```

Por último, [siempre usa el operador de igualdad `===`](http://www.2ality.com/2011/12/strict-equality-exemptions.html). El operador `==` solo compara valores, mientras que `===` compara valores y tipos, teniendo así una mejor fiabilidad.